# ag-grid-react failed in production

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I recently updated my react project to 18.2.0 and in the project, I'm using ag-grid-react, in develop mode it's working fine but in production, it causes failure, there is not any problem with code it fails even with just import.

my previous version was 24 the new one is 29
what should I do?

[image]

```
import {AgGridReact} from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const DashboardPage = () =>{
   return(
    <div className="ag-theme-material">

          <AgGridReact
            enableRtl={true}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={{ unSortIcon: true }}
            rowData={rowData}
            infiniteInitialRowCount={100}
            rowHeight={37}
            overlayLoadingTemplate={overlayLoadingTemplate}
            overlayNoRowsTemplate={overlayNoRowsTemplate}
            pagination={true}
            paginationPageSize={PASARGAD ? 40 : 15}
            localeText={{ to: 'To', of: 'Of', page: 'Page' }}
            rowSelection={'multiple'}
            onPaginationChanged={handlePagination}
            suppressRowClickSelection={true}
            onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
            onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}/>

        </div>
)};
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: here is my code, the rowData is coming from the server - @inkredusk